# python count number of occurence of the word

Tags: python

In the following string i want to count number of words that has occured before the first \tCart and ignore the rest of the string ,how can we do this

```
 str1="hi\thello\thow\tare\tyou\tCart\tagain\tCart"
 output expected:5
 str1.count() ?????
```

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
len(str1.split('\tCart')[0].split())
```

This does the following:

- Splits the string on the text `\tCart`, and takes only the first element of the result; this is everything *before* the tab + Cart.
- Splits the part before `\tCart` on whitespace (`\t` is a tab, and that is whitespace)
- The length of that split is the number of words.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - `len(str1.split('\tCart')[0].split())`.